# How to make a Soft Ripple Animation on React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I love this soft ripple animation and I would like to make it happen on React Native however, no idea how to do it :) I need some suggestions.

Here is the idea of soft ripple animation:

https://www.instagram.com/p/CBxl4KEgHm6

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use TouchableNativeFeedback to create a ripple effect

[Official Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablenativefeedback)

[With React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/touchable-ripple.html)

[More Reference](https://medium.com/react-native-motion/ripple-effect-in-react-native-1cb0ad568e91)

OR

Simply you can use [react-native-material-ripple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-ripple) npm library which can easily do your thing done :)

Comment: I know the ripple effect and this is not I am looking for. Have you checked the IG link which I share? 

I want the new soft ripple effect like a wave.

Answer (score 0):

thats a shimmer effect.

check out `react-native-shimmer-placeholder`

docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shimmer-placeholder

Comment: Hello, thank you but this is nothing similar with shimmer unfortunately :( This is literally soft ripple animation.